# How to compare two of the same fields in different data sets

Tags: reporting-services, fetchxml

I have these 2 datasets

- **Categories bought** which shows the categories the customer has bought from
- **All Categories** which is all the item categories

[image]

[image]

What i want to do is compare the **Categories Bought** psd_parentproductcategoryid and compare it with the **All Categories** psd_parentproductcategoryid to pick up the categories which don't appear in the **Categories Bought** results

I am using FetchXML and not SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a lookup for this:

```
=lookup(Fields!psd_parentproductcategoryid.Value,Fields!psd_parentproductcategoryid.Value.Value, Fields!psd_parentproductcategoryid.Value, "AllCategories")
```

The filter part is what can be tricky. I can't find my example but there is a way. Hopefully this can at least get you started.

**Edit

I have a paramter named Present. The value passed when I want to filter the dataset is 0.

Here is the filter code on the tablix:

```
=iif(Parameters!Present.Value = 0 , lookup(Fields!psd_parentproductcategoryid.Value,Fields!psd_parentproductcategoryid.Value.Value, Fields!psd_parentproductcategoryid.Value, "AllCategories") is nothing, "FALSE", "TRUE"), "TRUE")
```

**Edit 2
You can add this to your filter to only return values not present in your other data set.

```
IIF(=lookup(Fields!psd_parentproductcategoryid.Value,Fields!psd_parentproductcategoryid.Value.Value, Fields!psd_parentproductcategoryid.Value, "AllCategories") is nothing, Fields!psd_parentproductcategoryid.Value, nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks ISW :). Its a start, it returned the same values as Categories Bought Results, hopefully I can figure something else to return the ones that don't exist